# How do I use multiple handlers with one onClick?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to call two handlers, but only one of the handlers executes:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import classes from './Buy.module.css';
import HouseList from './HouseList';
import './style.css';

const Buy = () => {
  const [noOfCards, setNoOfCard] = useState(4);
  const [loadMore, setLoadMore] = useState('visible');

  const visibleHandler = () => {
    setNoOfCard((prevValue) => prevValue + 3);
  };

  const loadMoreHandler = () => {
    if (noOfCards === HouseList.length) {
      setLoadMore('inVisible');
    } else {
      setLoadMore('visible');
    }
    visibleHandler();
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.secondContainer}>
        <li className={classes.listingTitle}>Current Listings</li>
        <div className={classes.thirdContainer}>
          {HouseList.slice(0, noOfCards).map((houseL) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={houseL.id}
                className={classes.cardContainer}
                // onChange={loadMoreHandler}
              >
                <div className={classes.card}>
                  <img
                    src={houseL.image}
                    alt=''
                    className={classes.cardImage}
                  />
                  <button className={classes.cardButton}>House</button>
                  <br />
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <button onClick={loadMoreHandler} className={loadMore}>
          Load More
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Buy;
```

and this is the style.css file:

```
.visible {
  background-color: red;
}

.inVisible {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

Instead of calling visibleHandler inside loadMoreHandler, I've even tried calling both the functions onClick like so:

```
<button onClick={()=>{loadMoreHandler(); visibleHandler();}} className={loadMore}>
```

but it did not work.

How do I make the loadMoreHandler work once noOfCards equals to 11?

I tried calling my first handler function into my second one. I was expecting the loadmore button to disappear once the noOfCards's length reaches 11, which is the full length of my schema, HouseList. It works when I change the default value of noOfCards to 11 from 4, but that is not how I expected it to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can call two handlers in the form:

```
onClick={
 () => {
  handleA();
  handleB();
  }
}
```

as you stated.

If that doesn't work, likely another part of your code is performing in an unexpected way. Keep it mind state changes in `handleA` will not be reflected in the execution context of `handleB`.

Comment: Strange. As I mentioned, when I change the state of noOfCards (which I accidentally said was loadMore before) to 11, which is the full length of HouseList, the button works. So const [noOfCards, setNoOfCards] = useState(11); works, but when I change to lets say useState(4), it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

i think you just forgot something in className inside button,

try adding classes like this:

```
<button onClick={()=>{loadMoreHandler(); visibleHandler();}} className={classes.`${loadMore}`}>
```

Comment: Doing this will give you a syntax error. I don't think it's appropriate to use template literals after the dot of classes.